# str Memory Representation

Tags: string, rust

Why does a String in Rust have fixed size and str variable size? [The docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.str.html#representation) characterize a `str` as:

> a pointer to some bytes, and a length

A pointer + length sounds like a fixed size to me.

Answer (score 1):

A `String` is just a normal struct, and isn't built into the language, nor does it use any (substantive) compiler magic. `String`s are just wrappers around `Vec<u8>`. A `Vec` is a pointer to a buffer, along with a size and capacity to keep track of the buffer size. Thus a `String` has a size of thrice `usize` on the heap, along with a variable amount of heap storage.

A `&str` is "a pointer to some bytes, and a length". It's a fat pointer with a fixed size. Notice the ampersand: an `&str` is different from a `str`. A `str` is a [dynamically sized type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/exotic-sizes.html#dynamically-sized-types-dsts) that refers directly to the bytes of a string, without any reference or indirection. For the most part, you can't directly handle `str`s, since they don't have a fixed size, and so they must be handled behind a reference.

To summarize:

- That quote refers to `&str`, which is a fat pointer to some UTF-8 bytes
- A `str` refers to some UTF-8 bytes, and usually can't be handled without some indirection

Comment: When s is a String and one runs &s, it somehow turns into a &str. How is this possible? Is `str` not in fact bytes but an abstract type?

Comment: @Test `String` implements `Deref`, so when doing `&s` it can be [automatically dereferenced](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28519997/10113238) to a `str`, of which the reference is taken. The term used to describe `str` is a ["dynamically sized type"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/exotic-sizes.html#dynamically-sized-types-dsts). DSTs can't exist without having a reference to them.

Comment: I see, so &String is "str"? Or is "&String" converted to "&str"?

Comment: `&String` can be automatically converted to `&str` with this implementation - https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/alloc/string/struct.String.html#impl-Deref.

Comment: Also note that `&String` is like `&&str` and generally an anti-pattern (`&mut String` is fine, though).